# Indy Client TIdHTTP is causing error ws2tcpip.h(817): call to 'memcpy' is ambiguous

Tags: c++builder, indy, memcpy

I am using C++Builder 11 for a 64bit VCL Windows app. My program uses a 3rd party component name FlexCompress that has a function named `memcpy` listed in a machine generated header `.hpp` file.

When I add the Indy component `TIdHTTP` (version 10.6.2.0) to my application, I get this error:

```
[bcc64 Error] ws2tcpip.h(817): call to 'memcpy' is ambiguous
 mem.h(58): candidate function
 FXCZLib.hpp(150): candidate function
```

This is in the file `ws2tcpip.h(817)` and the two files with a function named `memcpy` is listed below the error.

The problem is that I don't believe I can safely modify any of these header files. Is there any work around for this?

In file `ws2tcpip.h`:

```
    if (Error == 0) {
        if (*SourceCount > 0) {
            CopyMemory(SourceList, Filter->imsf_slist,
                       *SourceCount * sizeof(*SourceList));
            *SourceCount = Filter->imsf_numsrc;
        }
        *FilterMode = Filter->imsf_fmode;
    }
```

In file `FXCZLib.hpp`:

```
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE void __cdecl memcpy(void * dest, void * Source, int Count);
```

In file `mem.h`:

```
void _FAR * _RTLENTRY  _EXPFUNC memcpy(void _FAR *__dest, const void _FAR *__src, _SIZE_T __n);
```

I didn't try anything because I'm afraid to modify these header files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with Indy itself. `ws2tcpip.h` is a standard Microsoft header file, and it has some inline functions that call `CopyMemory()`, which is just an alias for `memcpy()`. The error is because there are multiple `memcpy()` declarations in scope from different sources, one from the C runtime and one from FlexCompress, and the compiler doesn't know which one to use.  That has nothing to do with Indy.  FlexCompress should not be redeclaring `memcpy()` in the first place. That is something you should discuss with its author.

In the meantime, you should try reordering your header file includes so that FlexCompress's headers appear after Indy's headers.  Or, try to separate FlexCompress and Indy so they are not used in the same source unit together.